# A Problem With The Module "SimpleTCP" When Making a Chat Application

Tags: c#, .net, web, chat

So I wanted to make a chat app in C#, I watched a video about it(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ve2LX1tOwIM), I completely copied the code for now but when I run the server, Connect the client to the server and send a message from the client what happen is that it infinitely sends the message to both client and server. I am not sure why it does that since the code is exactly like shown in the video I watched. You can see this in my [repository](https://github.com/Noderdotbat/HyperChat-Server).

In case you want to see the code:
Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SimpleTCP;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class ClientForm : Form
    {
        SimpleTcpClient client;

        public ClientForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ClientForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new SimpleTcpClient();
            client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;
        }

        private void Client_DataReceived(Object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                txtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
                e.ReplyLine(String.Format("You: {0}", e.MessageString));
            });
        }

        private void SendMessageInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client.WriteLine(MessageInput.Text);
        }

        private void StartInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartInput.Enabled = false;
            client.Connect(HostInput.Text, Convert.ToInt32(PortInput.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

And that is the Server:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SimpleTCP;

namespace HyperChat
{
    public partial class ServerForm : Form
    {
        SimpleTcpServer server;

        public ServerForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ServerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            server = new SimpleTcpServer();
            server.Delimiter = 0x13;
            server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;
        }

        private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                txtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
                e.ReplyLine(String.Format("You: {0}", e.MessageString));
            });
        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtStatus.Text += "Server Started...";
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(hostInput.Text);
            server.Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32(portInput.Text));
            StartButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (server.IsStarted)
            {
                server.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate getting help, I tried messing up with my code but it didn't really work, I do want to mention that in the video they said you need to connect to get the IP you want to connect using:

```
System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(long.Parse(txtHost.Text))
```

But it gives errors and what you really need to do is:

```
System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(hostInput.Text);
```

What I expect to happen is the server to send the message like it should but for some reason it doesn't.
I would really appreciate getting help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have `e.ReplyLine…` in both the client and the server, remove that from the client and you code should work.

What is happening is that the client sends a message, which the server then receives and sends a reply to, the client receives the reply and in the case of your code sends a reply to the server, this results in the server receiving the reply and sending a reply to that and so on...

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to this was explained by @Chris Taylor and as he was saying what I’ve done is that the client sent the server a message, When the server gets a message he replys with a message, The client replys to the reply which makes an infinite loop. The way to solve this was to delete the line at the client that replys to the server and prevent the loop.
I really do appreciate the help, Thanks Chris.